# Web Worker profiling in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, profiling, developer-tools

According to this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255005(v=vs.85).aspx it is possible to profile Web Worker code in Internet Explorer 11 (11.576.14393 in my case) Developer Tools (F12). But when I finish profiling, I can see only report from code running on main thread and threre is no Worker ID colum in the results as described on the mentioned page. Also, when I try to programatically start profiling from the Web Worker using Console.profile() method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152133(v=vs.85).aspx, I get error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'profile'
```

Do you have any clue what may be wrong? Do you please know how to profile Web Worker code in Internet Explorer?

PS: Same applies to Edge 38.14393.0.0. Rewriting the Web Worker code to run and profile it on main thread is not an option because it would take several months. The same code runs reasonably fast on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to profile a simple web worker from the following demo
[Web Worker Demo](http://html5demos.com/worker)

It seems a bit weird but I was able to profile the worker only in the following scenario

I had started profiling the page and then started the worker and then stopped the worker and then stopped profiling.Exported the Data with Worker Id.

I had used IE11 in windows 7 environment.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried to profile this demo with procedure as you described and I see only worker-main.js code in the results without Worker ID column and with most of the time spending in moveSquare() which runs on UI thread. On which version of Windows and Internet Explorer are you trying that?

Comment: I tried it on Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 and it works there. I've been trying profiling on Windows 10 before. For some reason the Web Worker profiling works only on IE on Windows 7 and not Windows 10. Please add this information to you answer and I'll accept it as correct.